# Gulp.js access module.exports for each JS file in stream

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gulp

I've got a series of JS files that export JSON. I'd like to grab just the exported JSON from each file, so I can pipe it to another plugin. How would I access the module.exports of each file in the stream? Is there a plugin for this?

**Example JS file:**

```
let typographyFamilyFallback = 'Verdana, sans-serif';
let typographyFamily = 'Gotham, gotham, ' + typographyFamilyFallback;
let typographyFamilyFineprint = typographyFamily;
let typographyBaseSize = 15;

let typographyJSON = {
    typographyFamilyFallback,
    typographyFamily,
    typographyFamilyFineprint,
    typographyBaseSize
};

module.exports = typographyJSON;
```

**gulpfile.js:**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const jsonCss = require('gulp-json-css');

gulp.task('generate-less-vars', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(['./src/variables/*.js'])
    // Get the module.export and convert to json for the next piped task.
    .pipe(jsonCss({targetPre: 'less'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('target/static-zsg/zsg/variables/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

I have set number of .js files, so I construct an object with keys coming from the filename and the value being a require statement. Then the object is looped over. For each item I JSON.stringify the value, send that to gulp-file, pipe that to jsonCss and write to my target directory.

**JS File**

```
let typographyFamilyFallback = 'Verdana, sans-serif';
let typographyFamily = 'Gotham, gotham, ' + typographyFamilyFallback;
let typographyFamilyFineprint = typographyFamily;
let typographyBaseSize = 15;

let typographyJSON = {
    typographyFamilyFallback,
    typographyFamily,
    typographyFamilyFineprint,
    typographyBaseSize
};

module.exports = typographyJSON;
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const jsVars = {
    layout: require('./src/static-zsg/zsg/variables/_layout'),
    trapezoid: require('./src/static-zsg/zsg/variables/_trapezoid'),
    typography: require('./src/static-zsg/zsg/variables/_typography')
}
gulp.task('generate-less-vars', function() {
    for (let key in jsVars) {
        const variableJson = JSON.stringify(jsVars[key]);
        file(`${key}.json`, `${variableJson}`)
            .pipe(jsonCss({targetPre: 'less'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(`target/static-zsg/zsg/variables/`));
    }
});
```